# Vary list values according to seekbar progress

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to change the values of the items in my list view using the seekbar. I am getting a Cannot Reslove Constructor error when i try to write the code inside

`public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)`

My full code below.

```
package com.tshum.timestable;

import android.support.annotation.IntDef;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SeekBar timesControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        timesControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            final ListView TimesView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.TimesView);
            final ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, numbers);
                TimesView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The traceback occurs where i attempt to make an ArrayAdapter object in the method OnProgressChanged,

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, numbers);
```

How do i fix this traceback?

Attempts, but failed methods below

```
(getActivity(), R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
```

and

```
(activityName.this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
```

Comment: How about using seekBar.getContext() as first parameter to the Adapter's  constructor?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thank yo so much it rectified the error so far ;-)